# Filter MySQL plugins using SHOW PLUGINS command

Tags: mysql

#### Synopsis

The `SHOW PLUGINS` command for MySQL returns a tabular data set on MySQL 8.0.25. I would like to filter this data set using a `WHERE` clause. When I attempt this, I get a syntax error.

This works:

```
SHOW PLUGINS;
```

```
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+---------+
| Name                            | Status   | Type               | Library | License |
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+---------+
| binlog                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysql_native_password           | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| sha256_password                 | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| caching_sha2_password           | ACTIVE   | AUTHENTICATION     | NULL    | GPL     |
| sha2_cache_cleaner              | ACTIVE   | AUDIT              | NULL    | GPL     |
| daemon_keyring_proxy_plugin     | ACTIVE   | DAEMON             | NULL    | GPL     |
| CSV                             | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| MEMORY                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| InnoDB                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TRX                      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP                      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_RESET                | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM                   | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET             | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX            | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE              | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU          | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS        | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO          | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_METRICS                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD      | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_DELETED               | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED         | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_CONFIG                | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLES                   | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLESTATS               | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_INDEXES                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_TABLESPACES              | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_COLUMNS                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_VIRTUAL                  | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_CACHED_INDEXES           | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| INNODB_SESSION_TEMP_TABLESPACES | ACTIVE   | INFORMATION SCHEMA | NULL    | GPL     |
| MyISAM                          | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| MRG_MYISAM                      | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA              | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| TempTable                       | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| ARCHIVE                         | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| BLACKHOLE                       | ACTIVE   | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| FEDERATED                       | DISABLED | STORAGE ENGINE     | NULL    | GPL     |
| ngram                           | ACTIVE   | FTPARSER           | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysqlx_cache_cleaner            | ACTIVE   | AUDIT              | NULL    | GPL     |
| mysqlx                          | ACTIVE   | DAEMON             | NULL    | GPL     |
+---------------------------------+----------+--------------------+---------+---------+
```

This doesn't:

```
SHOW PLUGINS WHERE  Type = 'DAEMON';
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  Type = 'DAEMON'' at line 1

#### Question

How can I filter the list of plugins on a MySQL 8.0.25 server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most `SHOW` commands are aliases for queries against some table in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-plugins-table.html

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.plugins where plugin_type = 'DAEMON';
+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+
| PLUGIN_NAME | PLUGIN_VERSION | PLUGIN_STATUS | PLUGIN_TYPE | PLUGIN_TYPE_VERSION | PLUGIN_LIBRARY | PLUGIN_LIBRARY_VERSION | PLUGIN_AUTHOR      | PLUGIN_DESCRIPTION | PLUGIN_LICENSE | LOAD_OPTION |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+
| mysqlx      | 1.0            | ACTIVE        | DAEMON      | 80023.0             | NULL           | NULL                   | Oracle Corporation | X Plugin for MySQL | GPL            | ON          |
+-------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+----------------+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------+-------------+

mysql> select version();
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 8.0.23    |
+-----------+
```

Some `SHOW` command have syntax for a `WHERE` clause, but not all do. You can review which ones support a `WHERE` clause in the reference documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show.html

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. 